# Are there equivalents to "like", "you see", "all that" and "you know" filler words?

Tags: word-usage

For example:

> I was **like** going to eat my tie, **you know**.
>   He was so happy, **you see**,
>   about his new job and **all** (*that*).

How would the above look like in spoken Deutsch?

Comment: Have a look at *Modalpartikel*.

Comment: [This list](https://www.indoition.com/de/technical-writing-companion-de/de_schwarze_liste_fuellwoerter.html) is a starting point; in conversation depending on region some further "words", like *woll* and *ne*, *nich(t) wahr* may be mixed in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One difference between English and German seems to be that German textbooks and grammarians ignore features of informal spoken language such as filler words and phrases.

> **Und ich so** dann fress ich nen Besen **weißte (was ich mein)**.
>
> Er war so froh **weißte** wegen seiner neuen Arbeit **und so**.

Here, *weißte* is a contracted form of *weißt du*; *(und) so* is pretty close to *like*.

In the above example, I have used forms that are natural in informal spoken language, such as *fress* instead of *fresse*, *nen* for *einen*, *mein* for *meine*.

Comment: In my experience (French, tiny bit of Spanish, some Japanese), textbooks everywhere often ignore informal language, often to the detriment of the learner. Its a shame.

Comment: Informal or not, I would have added *considerably* more punctuation in those example sentences.

Comment: You know what I'm saying

Comment: These translations are correct. I have the feeling though, that these fillwords, especially _like_, are more common in english, especially in the US, than they are in german.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather go with something like this:

- **Weißt du**, ich war drauf und dran **regelrecht** meine Krawatte zu essen.
- Ich hätte bald **glatt** meine Krawatte gefressen, **glaubst du's**?
- **Boah**, ich hätte **echt** fast meine Krawatte runtergewürgt.
- Er hat sich so gefreut, **nicht wahr**, wegen des neuen Jobs **und so**.
- Er war **natürlich** ganz aus dem Häuschen mit seinem neuen Job **und Allem**.
- **Es ist so**, er war **halt** sehr glücklich mit seiner neuen Arbeit **usw.**.